# Checking for duplicate pins on an array

Tags: java

This is my first semester of java and first time on the website. This is one of our 3 final projects and I hit my wall, I have two weeks working on this and I cannot display a total.

The assignment is to create a bank account using a presentation class for the GUI and account class with all the calculations. on the presentations class, we create 3  panels: The first panel contains 3 radio buttons one to create an account, one to do a transaction (deposit or withdrawal) and the third button displays all accounts

In the second panel the client would first have to create an account inputting their first name last name, and pin. A textArea would then display the input info with a $100 beginning balance. I dont have a problem with that.
![panels][1]

In the third panel, the client could select if they want to deposit or withdrawal money and then input the amount. We had to create an array that can calculate at least 10 accounts. If they want to do a transaction, the array would have to be checked for a duplicate pin and if there is no duplicate, then the TextArea would display the pin, name, type of transaction, transaction amount and balance.

This is where my problem is, Im not sure if im checking for the duplicate pin correctly, and when I try to display, then I get a null pointer exception. Any direction to what Im doing wrong or an advise could be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

presentation class:

My problems are in method findPin2Duplicate(), and display transactions().. not sure if it is not displaying because of the find2Duplicate() or if it is because there is also a problem with it.

```
import javax.swing.*;       //needed for swing components

import java.awt.*;          //needed for ItemListener and ActionListener interfaces
import java.awt.event.*;    //needed for Font class
import java.text.DecimalFormat;



public class Presentation extends JFrame 
    implements ActionListener
{

        //Declare components
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("The Friendly NeighborHood Bank");
        //intro panel
        JRadioButton createAccountRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Create New Account");
        JRadioButton transactionRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Deposit or Withdrawal");
        JRadioButton displayRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Display all accounts");
        JRadioButton default1RadioButton = new JRadioButton();
        ButtonGroup introButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        //new account panel
        JTextField firstNameTextField = new JTextField (20);
        JTextField lastNameTextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField pin1TextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextArea output1TextArea = new JTextArea(18,45);
        JButton process1Button = new JButton ("Process");
        JButton back1Button = new JButton ("Back");
        //deposit or withdrawal panel
        JRadioButton depositRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Deposit");
        JRadioButton withdrawalRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Withdrawal");
        JRadioButton default2RadioButton = new JRadioButton();
        ButtonGroup transactionButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        JTextField pin2TextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField amountTextField = new JTextField(20);
        JTextArea output2TextArea = new JTextArea(20,30);
        JButton process2Button = new JButton ("Process");
        JButton back2Button = new JButton ("Back");



        JScrollPane outputScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(output1TextArea);
        JScrollPane outputScrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(output2TextArea);

        Font plainFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        Font taFont = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 12);

        JPanel introPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel newAccountPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel transactionPanel = new JPanel();




        //declare instance variables
        Account myAccountArray[] = new Account[10];
        int lastAccountInteger = -1;
        int pinIndexInteger = 0;


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            // This method creates sets the default close operation
            Presentation myProgram = new Presentation();
            myProgram.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }//end of main method

        //This is the constructor and will call the 3 panels to add the components to the GUI, 
        //register the listeners, and set the properties of the JFrame
        public Presentation()
        {

            super("Account");
            //Constructor - calls methods to add components to panel, set up 
            //the listeners, and set properties for the JFrame
            introPanel();
            newAccountPanel();
            transactionPanel();
            //Call method to add controls and set listeners
            addListeners();


            //add the intro panel to the frame and set the size and the visibility of the frame

            add(introPanel);
            setSize(200,300);
            setVisible(true);

        }


        // This method will add components to the first panel shown
        public void introPanel()
        {

            introButtonGroup.add(createAccountRadioButton);
            introButtonGroup.add(transactionRadioButton);
            introButtonGroup.add(displayRadioButton);
            introButtonGroup.add(default1RadioButton);

            createAccountRadioButton.setSelected(false);
            transactionRadioButton.setSelected(false);
            displayRadioButton.setSelected(false);
            default1RadioButton.setSelected(true);

            introPanel.add(titleLabel);
            introPanel.add(createAccountRadioButton);
            introPanel.add(transactionRadioButton);
            introPanel.add(displayRadioButton);
        }
        //This method will add components to a second panel
        public void newAccountPanel()
        {

            newAccountPanel.add(titleLabel);

            newAccountPanel.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
            newAccountPanel.add(firstNameTextField);
            newAccountPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
            newAccountPanel.add(lastNameTextField);
            newAccountPanel.add(new JLabel("PIN:"));
            newAccountPanel.add(pin1TextField);

            output1TextArea.setFont(taFont);
            String formattedTitleString = String.format("%-10s%13s%15s%n", "Name", 
                    "PIN",  "Balance");
            output1TextArea.append(formattedTitleString);
            newAccountPanel.add(output1TextArea);
            newAccountPanel.add(new JLabel(" Programmed by: Maria Garcia "));

            newAccountPanel.add(process1Button);
            newAccountPanel.add(back1Button);
        }

        //This method will add components to a third panel
        public void transactionPanel()
        {

            transactionButtonGroup.add(depositRadioButton);
            transactionButtonGroup.add(withdrawalRadioButton);
            transactionButtonGroup.add(default2RadioButton);

            depositRadioButton.setSelected(false);
            withdrawalRadioButton.setSelected(false);
            default2RadioButton.setSelected(true);

            transactionPanel.add(titleLabel);
            transactionPanel.add(depositRadioButton);
            transactionPanel.add(withdrawalRadioButton);
            transactionPanel.add( new JLabel ("PIN:"));
            transactionPanel.add(pin2TextField);
            transactionPanel.add(new JLabel ("Amount:"));
            transactionPanel.add(amountTextField);
            output2TextArea.setFont(taFont);
            String formattedTitleString = String.format("%-8s%11s%13s%11s%13s%n", "PIN", 
                    "Name",  "Transaction Type ",   "Transaction Amount",   "Balance");
            output2TextArea.setText(formattedTitleString);
            transactionPanel.add(output2TextArea);
            transactionPanel.add(new JLabel(" Programmed by: Maria Garcia "));
            transactionPanel.add(process2Button);
            transactionPanel.add(back2Button);
        }
        public void addListeners()
        {
            //This method sets up the listeners
            //radio buttons set up to respond to the ItemListener

            process1Button.addActionListener(this);
            back1Button.addActionListener(this);
            process2Button.addActionListener(this);
            back2Button.addActionListener(this);
            amountTextField.addActionListener(this);

            createAccountRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
            transactionRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
            displayRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
            depositRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
            withdrawalRadioButton.addActionListener(this);
        }//end of addListeners method




           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                {

                Object sourceObject = evt.getSource();  


                    if(sourceObject == createAccountRadioButton)
            {
                if(createAccountRadioButton.isSelected())
                {
                    remove(introPanel);
                    default1RadioButton.setSelected(true);
                    remove(transactionPanel);
                    add(newAccountPanel);
                    setSize(420,475);
                    setVisible(true);
                }
            } //to display the admin panel
            else if(sourceObject == transactionRadioButton )
            {
                if(transactionRadioButton.isSelected())
                {

                    remove(introPanel);
                    default2RadioButton.setSelected(true);
                    remove(newAccountPanel);
                    add(transactionPanel);
                    setSize(420,500);
                    setVisible(true);
                }
            }
                    if(sourceObject == process1Button)
                    {

                        if(newAccountValidation() == true) // validation method will be called and then the processRental
                        {



                                displayNewAccount();




                        }    
                    }
                    else if (sourceObject ==process2Button )
                    {
                        if(transactionsValidation() == true)
                        {
                            if(findPin2Duplicate()== false)
                            {

                                displayTransactions();
                                //reset();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else if ( sourceObject == back1Button) //If the summary button is pressed then the summary method will be called
                    {
                        remove(newAccountPanel);
                        add(introPanel);
                        setSize(200,300);
                        setVisible(true);

                    }
                    else if (sourceObject == back2Button)
                    {
                        remove(transactionPanel);
                        add(introPanel);
                        setSize(200,300);
                        setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else if (displayRadioButton.isSelected())
                    {
                        summary();
                    }

                }
                    public boolean newAccountValidation()
                    {
                        boolean newAccountValidationBoolean;
                        if(!(firstNameTextField.getText()).equals(""))
                        {
                            if(!(lastNameTextField.getText()).equals(""))
                            {
                                if (!(pin1TextField.getText()).equals(""))
                                {
                                    newAccountValidationBoolean = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your pin");
                                    pin1TextField.requestFocus();
                                    newAccountValidationBoolean = false;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your last name");
                                lastNameTextField.requestFocus();
                                newAccountValidationBoolean = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your first name");
                            firstNameTextField.requestFocus();
                            newAccountValidationBoolean = false;

                        }
                        return newAccountValidationBoolean;
                    }

                    public boolean transactionsValidation()
                    {
                        boolean transactionsValidationBoolean;
                        if(!(pin2TextField.getText()).equals(""))
                        {
                            if(!(amountTextField.getText()).equals(""))
                            {
                                transactionsValidationBoolean = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter an amount");
                                amountTextField.requestFocus();
                                transactionsValidationBoolean = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your pin");
                            pin2TextField.requestFocus();
                            transactionsValidationBoolean = false;

                        }
                        return transactionsValidationBoolean;
                    }







                   public void displayNewAccount()
                   {
                       String firstNameString = ("");
                       String lastNameString = ("");
                       String pinString = ("");

                       DecimalFormat valueDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");

                       if (lastAccountInteger >= 0) //don't want to do this for the first account
                       {
                           if(findPin1Duplicate() == false)
                           {


                               lastAccountInteger ++;
                               myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger]= new Account(firstNameString, lastNameString, pinString);
                               String nameString = lastNameTextField.getText() + ", " + firstNameTextField.getText();
                               double Amount = (myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getBalance());
                               String tempString1 = Double.toString(Amount);


                               output1TextArea.append(nameString + "\t    " + pin1TextField.getText() + "\t " + "$" + tempString1 + "\n");
                       //String formattedOutputString = String.format("%6s%9s%13s%n", nameString, myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getTransactionAmount(transactionAmountDouble)); 
                       //myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getPin();
                        //output1TextArea.append(formattedOutputString);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               String displayString = "Enter a valid Pin";
                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayString);
                           }
                               //JOptionPane message
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           lastAccountInteger ++;
                           myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger]= new Account(firstNameString, lastNameString, pinString);
                           String nameString = lastNameTextField.getText() + ", " + firstNameTextField.getText();
                           double Amount = (myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getBalance());
                           String tempString1 = Double.toString(Amount);


                           output1TextArea.append(nameString + "\t    " + pin1TextField.getText() + "\t " + "$" + tempString1 + "\n");


                       }
                   }

                   public void displayTransactions()
                   {
                       String firstNameString = ("");
                       String lastNameString = ("");
                       String pinString = ("");
                       char typeOfTransactionChar = (' ');
                       String transactionString = ("");
                       double transactionAmountDouble = 0.0;
                       double amountDouble = 0.0;



                      //for (int i = 0; i < lastAccountInteger; i++)
                       lastAccountInteger++;
                       myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger]= new Account(firstNameString, lastNameString, pinString);
                           if (lastAccountInteger >= 0)
                           {

                       if (depositRadioButton.isSelected())
                       {
                          amountDouble =myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getDeposit();
                          //typeOfTransactionChar ='D';
                           transactionString = "Deposit";
                           //transactionAmountDouble = depositAmountDouble ;
                       }

                       else if( withdrawalRadioButton.isSelected())
                       {
                        amountDouble = myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getWithdrawal();
                           //typeOfTransactionChar= 'W';
                          transactionString = "Withdrawal";
                           //transactionAmountDouble = withdrawalAmountDouble;
                       }


                       }
                           String nameString = lastNameTextField.getText() + ", " + firstNameTextField.getText();

                           String tempString = Double.toString(amountDouble);
                    output2TextArea.append(pinString + nameString + transactionString + amountDouble); 
                    //String formattedTransactionString = String.format("%-10s%6s%9s%9s%13s%11s%n", transactionString); //6d=decimal integer



                    // output2TextArea.append(formattedTransactionString);
                   }
                    public boolean findPin1Duplicate()
                    {
                        boolean itemFoundBoolean = false;
                        pinIndexInteger = 0;
                        String listItemString;
                        lastAccountInteger++;
                        String pinString = myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getPin();
                        String inputPin1String = pin1TextField.getText();
                        int arrayPin1Sum = 0;



                        while (!itemFoundBoolean && pinIndexInteger < lastAccountInteger)
                        {

                            //listItemString = String.valueOf(arrayPin1Sum);

                            if(inputPin1String.equalsIgnoreCase(pinString))
                            {
                                itemFoundBoolean = true;
                            }
                            else
                                pinIndexInteger++;
                        }

                        return itemFoundBoolean;
                    }
                    public boolean findPin2Duplicate()
                    {
                        boolean itemFoundBoolean = false;
                        pinIndexInteger = 0;
                        lastAccountInteger ++;
                        String pin2String = myAccountArray[lastAccountInteger].getPin();
                        String inputPin1String = pin2TextField.getText();
                        int arrayPin2Sum = 0;

                    //  for (int i = 0; i < myAccountArray.length; i++)
                        //{
                            //pin2String += myAccountArray[i].getPin();
                        //}

                        while (!itemFoundBoolean && pinIndexInteger < lastAccountInteger)
                        {

                            //listItemString = String.valueOf(arrayPin2Sum);

                            if(inputPin1String.equalsIgnoreCase(pin2String))
                            {

                                itemFoundBoolean = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            pinIndexInteger++;
                            }
                        }

                        return itemFoundBoolean;
                    }



                    //method to display summary

                        public void summary()
                        {
                            //Format the values to currency format
                            DecimalFormat valueDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");



                        }




                //This method resets the textfields for re-entry and sends the cursor to the nameTextField      
                    public void reset()
                            {




                            } //end of reset method

}


Account Class

   public class Account
{


//declare instance variables



    //constants
    private final double DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_DOUBLE = 100.0;


    //class variables
    private double withdrawalAmountDouble;
    private static double currentBalanceDouble;
    private double totalAmountDouble;

    private static double totalCount;
    private static double totalDepositDouble;
    private double depositAmountDouble;
    private static String firstNameString;
    private static String lastNameString;
    private static String fullNameString;
    private static String pinString;
    private static double addedAmountDouble;
    private static String transactionTypeString;
    private static boolean balanceBoolean;
    private static char typeOfTransactionChar;
    private static double transactionAmountDouble;
    private static double totalWithdrawalAmountDouble;
    private static double totalDepositAmountDouble;
    private static double grossTransactionDouble;
    private static double balanceDouble;
    private static boolean isValidBoolean;




    //Constructors
    public Account()
    {
        setFirstName("");
        setLastName("");
        setPin("");





        totalCount++;
    }

    public Account(String newFirstNameString, String newLastNameString, String newPinString) 
    {
        setFirstName(newFirstNameString);
        setLastName(newLastNameString);
        setPin(newPinString);
        setBalance(DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_DOUBLE);

    }



    public void setFirstName(String newFirstNameString)
        {
            firstNameString = newFirstNameString;
        }

    public void setLastName(String newLastNameString)
        {
            lastNameString = newLastNameString;
        }

    public void setPin(String newPinString)
        {
            pinString = newPinString;
        }


        //this method will set the type of transaction for the transaction panel
    public void setBalance(double newBalanceDouble)
    {

        balanceDouble = newBalanceDouble;
    }   


        public String getTypeOfTransaction()
        {

            return transactionTypeString;
        }
        public double getBalance()
        {
            return balanceDouble;
        }
        public double getTransactionAmountDouble()
        {
            return transactionAmountDouble;
        }


        public double getTransactionAmount(double newTransactionAmountDouble)
        {

            currentBalanceDouble = DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_DOUBLE;

            transactionAmountDouble = currentBalanceDouble;
            return transactionAmountDouble;
        }


        public String getFirstNameString()
        {
            return firstNameString;
        }
        public String getLastNameString()
        {
            return lastNameString;
        }
        public void setName()
        {

            fullNameString = (firstNameString + " , " + lastNameString);

        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return fullNameString;
        }


        public void setIsValid(double newBalanceDouble)
        {
            if (balanceDouble > currentBalanceDouble)
            {
                isValidBoolean = false;
            }



        }

        public void setDeposit(double newDepositDouble)
        {
            balanceDouble += newDepositDouble;


        }
        public void setWithdrawal(double newWithdrawalDouble)
        {


                    balanceDouble -= (newWithdrawalDouble);




        }

        public double getDeposit()
        {
            return balanceDouble;
        }
        public double getWithdrawal()
        {
            return balanceDouble;
        }
        public boolean getIsValid()
        {
            return isValidBoolean;
        }



        public String getPin()
        {
            return pinString;
        }
        }
```

Again anything that can lead me into the right direction or point me to where my mistakes are is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at the formatting of your post, and fix it.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception. That tells precisely where the exception occurs (tell us which line it is).

Comment: there is a huge amount of code...

Comment: Sorry to say this, but seeing this code makes me swirl. One obvious smell in the logic is the (mis)use of lastAccountInteger. I am not sure why it should be modified in the 2 methods that check for duplicate pins. Can you instead consider using a temporary variable than mutating lastAccountInteger

Comment: @JBNizet is correct, if you post the stack trace from the NullPointerException, it will indicate precisely which line of code is encountering the problem.  Without it, we can't help.  Also, this is a huge amount of code for such little work.  I suggest you look for ways to simplify it.

Comment: It would also help to show the minimal amount of relevant code.  For example, if you have a method which scans an array for duplicate values and that method is not working right, show us the method along with the necessary context (like how it is called, the life cycle of the array).  We don't need the source to the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the question is, so I will first start with the NullPointerException.  Without a full stack trace, we can't help.  Include the stack trace to indicate which line is encountering the error.

If you are trying to ask how to find duplicates in an array, then I can help.  But I'm still not clear on what you are trying to do.  Do you simply want to know if an array contains duplicates?  Do you need to de-dup the array?  Or identify which values are repeated?

### To Prevent Duplicates

Arrays are not the right data structure if duplicates are problem.  Consider a set.  Since this is Java, you have a TreeSet and HashSet available.

### To Identify The Presence of Duplicates

2 things I would try:

1. Copy every element into an HashSet and compare the sizes.  If the HashSet has fewer elements than the array, then there must have been duplicate values.
2. Sort the array and then write a loop that compares each value to the value before it.  Sorting will ensure that duplicate values are adjacent, so comparing every value to the value before it will reveal duplicates easily.

### To Identify Which Values are Duplicated

- Create an empty array called "dups".
- Sort the original array.
- Iterate over the original array comparing each value to the one before it.
- If you find a match, add that value to the "dups" array.
- At the end of your loop, "dups" will contain values which occurred multiple times in the original array.